# Class WebSwapCGLLayer is implemented in both Mac OS X /System and node_modules

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules

I am completely new to using node and electron. I was running through the [getting started docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start) and after running `npm start` as described when I encountered the following error:

`Class WebSwapCGLLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libANGLE-shared.dylib (0x7ffa5dba6318) and myProjectDir/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLESv2.dylib (0x10d69b9c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

How can I specify that the class contained in `node_modules` should be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a warning and Electron.js should start fine, see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/33685 and upstream Chromium issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=7123

Comment: So, how to get rid of it?

Comment: Would love to see other answers that help get rid of warning… this is especially helpful in the context of Electron apps with CLI interface.

Comment: It's a Chromium issue. You would have to recompile Chromium and Electron to get rid of it. Or wait until it's fixed. Or make some wrapper to intercept stderr of Electron process, e.g. see [silence-chromium](https://github.com/beaugunderson/silence-chromium)

Comment: Guys in Electron have decided not to wait for Chromium and pathed it by themself, see [PR 35961](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/35961). So, next release (21.3.4, 22) should be without this warning.